# Bundle Text file in py2app Application (python)

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, py2app

I recently learned Python (2.7) and have been making some simple board games with AIs and such as practice.  I am currently making an intelligent hangman game which necessitates the inclusion of a dictionary file.  (I have a text file which has a new word on each line). I used py2app successfully for other stuff such as this: [connect-four.zzl.org](http://connect-four.zzl.org) but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to include my text file when I run py2app for my new hangman program.  Can anyone help me figure out how to include this file so that the program can be distributed like the connect four game I linked to?

Thank You very much.  (I am running OS X 10.7 and can provide any other necessary info if necessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a resources key in your options that contains a list of resources to include. This will be the current directory when your app runs

options = { "resources": ["myfile.txt"] }

http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html#option-reference

If you use the resources flag with py2applet it will creates that key

Comment: Awesome!  I tried it right below my icon specification, and it worked.  Many thanks.

Comment: actually, I thought that this would work in the same manner for py2exe, but it did not.  I wrote this:  distutils.core.setup(
      windows=[
            {'script': 'hangman.py',
             'icon_resources': [(1, 'HangIcon.ico')],
             'other_resources': [(1, '2of12inf.txt')]}
      ],

Comment: Your question says you are using py2app. If you wanted a py2exe specific answer make sure to say so :)

Comment: I wanted a py2app answer, and I had figured that once I understood that, I could figure out the py2exe answer - but I wasn't able to.  I will post a new thread, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

[From the help document for py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html):

> The first step is to create a `setup.py` file for your script. `setup.py`
>   is the "project file" that tells setuptools everything it needs to
>   know to build your application. We'll use the `py2applet` script to do
>   that:
>
> `$ py2applet --make-setup MyApplication.py`
>
> `Wrote setup.py`
>
> If your application has an icon (in .icns format) or data files that
>   it requires, you should also specify them as arguments to `py2applet`.

So presuming you have `hangman.py` and `hangman.txt` run:

`$ py2applet --make-setup hangman.py hangman.txt`

Comment: Thank you for responding.  as "jdi" said, the correct way to do it is specifying it as options = { "resources": ["myfile.txt"] }.

Comment: @user1104215: Both methods work.  Be sure to click the green check mark next to the answer that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is to add your dictionary as a (variable in a) python module that you import at run time. The dictionary will be embedded in your exe as any other module.