# How to create installer for mac osx

Tags: python, macos, py2exe, egg, dmg

I am making an app in python, which is able to open different file types. This code in running fine on eclipse while passing filename which I want to open and configuration file as arguments respectively. Now I converted this into application by using py2app. So, the issue is how to deal with arguments, as different file types need to be open through app and this app also needs configuration file while processing. Is there any different methods available for making app which can be installed on mac osx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at [py2app](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/)? Its pretty much py2exe for Mac OSX and creates a standalone app. You can handle the logger and configuration files pretty easily and keep your app nice and simple to distribute.

I usually store logger files in the users home directory as a hidden file - a lot of Mac OSX applications do this - i'm not sure if its officially the way to go but it works. The home directory is guaranteed to exist and you won't get permission errors like you would when you write to other random folders or to location inside the app bundle.

You can do this and keep your code cross platform buy opening files like this

```
import platform
import os

if platform.system() == 'Darwin': # We're on a mac
        # Store the saved rates in the users home dir - note the dot at the start
        # of the filename to keep the file hidden
        home = os.path.expanduser("~")
        filename = os.path.join(home, '.myHiddenLogger')

else: # We're on another platform, create whatever filename you were using before
        filename = 'myLogger'
```

As for the configuration file, this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550374/bundle-text-file-in-py2app-application-python) tells you how to bundle a resource file in with you're app. If you want to write stuff to this configuration file and save it for next time, you'll have to store it as a hidden file like the logger - this will stop the app from crashing due to permission errors when it tried to write to a file inside the app bundle.

Comment: In my app, I call for the webservices and authentication through web-browser and webbrowser.open(). I am reading the configuration files for path and server IP. Also I want to change the SERVER IP if needed, after the app is installed on MAC. Is it all possible through py2app

Comment: Yes, you would include the initial configuration file as a resource file when building the app by using the [-resources command line option when generating your setup.py with py2applet](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/py2applet.html). Then when your program is launched, it can check to see if a hidden configuration file is in the home directory of the user and if not it will create one which is a copy of the one that you included in the bundle. Now this hidden one can be read from and updated with a new server IP if necessary, and each users configuration on that machine will be unique to them.

Comment: Also the user can move the app bundle around and run it from wherever they want and you don't have to worry about trying to figure out where the configuration file is - it'll always be hidden in their home directory.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion. I kept my setup.py,myapp.py cc.icns,config.cfg in user/fis/Desktop location. Then dist and build folder is generated. Inside dist, myapp is present with the desired logo. Within Resources, there is config.cfg file is present. This app is basically like notepad++. So, when you install this app, and double click on any file, the file should open with this app.

Comment: Now when, i click on myapp within dist, it shows error of console, terminal. Then I selected any file, and tried with openwith myapp. It shows this error 17/10/13 10:48:01.955 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[130]: ([0x0-0x1f51f5].org.pythonmac.unspecified.myapp[2144]) Exited with code: 255. So, Do I need to install this app. If yes, then how? In pyhton code, I am passing the config.cfg file and the desired file to open as argument. Also, myapp is not present in Application location on mac.Please reply

Comment: I'd need more details to help you figure out what the problem is. It's probably best to open another question with all the details about what's going on.

Comment: Aim of my app is to open a file just like notepad++ does. In windows, through py2exe, i created the .exe file and installed on system. So, when this app in installed, and then if you double click on any file, the file will open. Just like this I am making in mac osx. So, how to install this on mac the, myapp.app which is generated in dist folder.

Comment: I am passing filename which I want to open through this app, and config.cfg file as argument in code. How to deal with this in the app which is generated in dist folder. In setup.py file, I gave config.cfg file. So, in resources of app, config.cfg file is present. Now, the error is coming, list out of index